# Calculate sum for different data types in Django

Tags: django, sum, calculated-columns

I have columns in db called as Price and Qty. Price is the textfield because it requires to be written as $ 12 (for example). While Qty is integer.

But when i run my code. it shows an error

```
    sum_count = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=OrderId).aggregate(total_price=Sum('Total_Price:' 'Price[2:]' * 'Qty'))

    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      Table_No = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
      FoodId = models.TextField()
      Item = models.TextField()
      Qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
      Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
      TotalPrice = models.TextField()
      Note = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
      OrderId = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def cashier_view(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
         OrderId = request.POST.get("OrderId")
         customerOrder = OrderItem(OrderId=OrderId)
         cv = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=OrderId)\
                  .annotate(total_price=Sum(F("Price") * 
               F("Qty"),output_field=models.DecimalField()))
         grand_total = OrderItem.objects.update(TotalPrice=total_price)
         return render(request, 'restaurants/cashier_page.html', {'cv': cv})
     else:
         return render(request, 'restaurants/cashier_view.html')
```

cashier_page.html

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for order in cv%}
             <table width="800">
             <tr>
                <th width="800">Table Number</th>
                <th width="800">Item</th>
                <th width="800">Quantity</th>
                <th width="800">Price</th>
                <th width="800">Order Id</th>
                <th width="800">Total Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Table_No }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Item }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Qty }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Price }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.OrderId }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.TotalPrice }}</td>
             </tr>
      </table>
  {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

The result should be able to do the total_price calculations based on OrderId and show it to the template.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> aggregate(total_price=Sum('Total_Price:' 'Price[2:]' * 'Qty'))
> ```

Isn't really valid syntax. In order to do the above, you would need something like

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Substr


annotate(price_str=Substr('price', 3))\
.annotate(price_int=Cast('price_str', FloatField())).\
.aggregate(total_price=Sum(F("price_int") * F("Qty"),
                           output_field=models.FloatField()))
```

However, this isn't an ideal way to go about it. You might find it more helpful to actually store the price in the database as a `DecimalField` -- or something similar -- and not as text. It's better to do the preprocessing on that text to turn it into a number, and then store that in the database.

If the price was a number, then the entire query would simply be

```
aggregate(total_price=Sum(F("Price") * F("Qty"), output_field=models.FloatField()))
```

---

**edit**

Ok, in this case you actually want to `annotate` instead, so try:

```
from django.db import models

cv = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=OrderId)\
                      .annotate(total_price=Sum(F("Price") * F("Qty"), 
                                     output_field=models.DecimalField()))
```

and you access it with `.total_price`, so:

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for order in cv%}
             <table width="800">
             <tr>
                <th width="800">Table Number</th>
                <th width="800">Item</th>
                <th width="800">Quantity</th>
                <th width="800">Price</th>
                <th width="800">Order Id</th>
                <th width="800">Total Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Table_No }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Item }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Qty }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Price }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.OrderId }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.total_price }}</td>
             </tr>
      </table>
  {% endfor %}
 </form>
```

---

To store it in the database, you would need to have a field in `OrderItem`. I see that you have a `TextField` called `TotalPrice`, but assuming you change it to `DecimalField` then the views would be

```
# . . .
OrderId = request.POST.get("OrderId")
customerOrder = OrderItem(OrderId=OrderId)
customerOrder.TotalPrice = customerOrder.Price * customerOrder.Qty
customerOrder.save()
```

to add to an existing order. You could also set this value when creating a new order, the same as you already do. If you always store the total price in the database, then you don't even need any of the query operations above, but can simply access it directly.

Comment: I change the data types to DecimalField for both. But when i run my views.py, it only shows the empty table. Can you help me with this problem? I already edit my views.py

Comment: it shows an error .annotate(total_price=Sum(F("Price") * F("Qty"),output_field=models.DecimalField()))
NameError: name 'models' is not defined

Comment: add `from django.db import models`

Comment: it works yeay, thank you so much. And may i ask one question again? which is how to save the total_price to the database?

Comment: Sure, added some thoughts.

Comment: I have a new views.py which shows the way i want to save the data into database. But, it shows an error which is grand_total = OrderItem.objects.update(TotalPrice=total_price)
NameError: name 'total_price' is not defined

Comment: And then i try with your code. It shows an error which is   customerOrder.TotalPrice = customerOrder.Price * customerOrder.Qty
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'